# I have profiled Visual Studio 2010 and CUDA 4.0 with Geforce GT 540M,but the IDE don't know some key words

Tags: c, cuda

It shows many errors by underlining many right words with red lines,but I can run it correctly.These words includes C key words and CUDA key words.Could you help me?
I'm sorry ,I don't have 10 reputations to post a picture,maybe a picture is more clear.

Comment: Please post code and give some examples.

Comment: OK，I will post my code right now

Comment: I think add a picture may be in details

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The problem is that the IDE tries to parse the files on its own, independently of nvcc, but it does not understand some keywords. As a result, it makes some wrong assumptions (e.g. thinks that `__global__` is a name of a variable/function and then gets confused that there is another name after it and ignores it) and then and then everything falls apart from him.

Since Visual Studio's IDE assumes `_MSC_VER` is declared, while CUDA compiler assumes that `__CUDACC__` is declared instead, you can differentiate between what IDE and what CUDA parses in.

So, what I did is to create a helper header file `sense.h` which I include at the very beginning of all `.cu` files (and only those files). Inside the `sense.h` I define all CUDA-specific keywords as macros:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
/*
Include this file at the very beginning of your .cu files to make Visual Studio IntelliSense more compatible with it.
Do -NOT- include it in .cpp files or header files
*/

#if !defined(__CUDACC__)
//unfortunately there is no IntelliSense macro.
//Fortunately, __CUDACC__ is not defined when IntelliSense parses the file.

#define __CUDACC__
#include <host_defines.h>
#include <device_functions.h>

#ifndef __device__
#define __device__
#endif

#ifndef __host__
#define __host__
#endif

#ifndef __global__
#define __global__
#endif

#ifndef __forceinline__
#define __forceinline__ __forceinline
#endif

#endif
#endif
```

Comment: en,and it can't autofill the function and key,that's bad